# laravel livewire not executing methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i get this error when displaying a list of users in my livewire component

```
livewire.js?id=2f6e5d4d:347 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'role')
    at livewire.js?id=2f6e5d4d:347:19
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at dataGet (livewire.js?id=2f6e5d4d:344:27)
    at Object.get (livewire.js?id=2f6e5d4d:7530:20)
    at getValue (livewire.js?id=2f6e5d4d:3288:46)
    at livewire.js?id=2f6e5d4d:3344:19
    at reactiveEffect (livewire.js?id=2f6e5d4d:2388:18)
    at Object.effect2 [as effect] (livewire.js?id=2f6e5d4d:2363:7)
    at effect (livewire.js?id=2f6e5d4d:784:35)
    at wrappedEffect (livewire.js?id=2f6e5d4d:800:29)
```

below is my blade file

```
<div>
    <div class="mb-6 md:ml md:w-1/3 ml-2 mr-2 sm:w-full">
        <x-input wire:model.live="search" placeholder="Search users..." class="w-full" id="search"/>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-white overflow-y-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg ml-2 mr-2 rounded-md">
        {{--Users table--}}
        <x-table.table>
            <x-slot name="head">
                <x-table.table-heading class="px-6 py-6">
                    Profile photo
                </x-table.table-heading>
                <x-table.table-heading style="white-space: nowrap;"
                                       class="px-6 py-6">
                    Name
                </x-table.table-heading>
                <x-table.table-heading style="white-space: nowrap;"
                                       class="px-6 py-6">
                    Email
                </x-table.table-heading>
                <x-table.table-heading style="white-space: nowrap;"
                                       class="px-6 py-6">
                    Role
                </x-table.table-heading>
                <x-table.table-heading style="white-space: nowrap;"
                                       class="px-6 py-6">
                    Verified
                </x-table.table-heading>
                <x-table.table-heading style="white-space: nowrap;"
                                       class="px-6 py-6">
                    Created
                </x-table.table-heading>
                <x-table.table-heading style="white-space: nowrap;"
                                       class="px-6 py-6">
                    Actions
                </x-table.table-heading>
            </x-slot>
            <x-slot name="body">
                @forelse ($users as $user)
                    <tr class="bg-white border-b"
                        wire:loading.class.delay="opacity-50" wire:key="row-{{ $user->id }}">
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 text-gray-900">
                            @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::managesProfilePhotos())
                                <button class="flex text-sm border-2 border-transparent rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-300 transition">
                                    <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover" src="{{ $user->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ $user->name }}" />
                                </button>
                            @else
                            <span class="inline-flex rounded-md">
                                <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm leading-4 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-500 bg-white hover:text-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-50 active:bg-gray-50 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                                    {{ $user->name }}
                                    <svg class="ml-2 -mr-0.5 h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor">
                                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5" />
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td class="py-4 text-gray-900">
                            {{ strtoupper($user->name) }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 text-gray-900">
                            {{ $user->email }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 text-gray-900">
                            @if($user->role == 'admin')
                                <div class="text-red-800 font-semibold">
                                    Administrator
                                </div>
                            @elseif($user->role == 'staff')
                                <div class="text-orange-700 font-semibold">
                                    Staff
                                </div>
                            @else
                                <div class="text-gray-400 font-semibold">
                                    {{ $user->role }}
                                </div>
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 text-gray-900">
                            @if($user->email_verified_at)
                                Yes
                            @else
                                No
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 text-gray-900">
                            {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 text-gray-900">
                            @if($user->role == 'admin')
                                <div class="text-xs text-red-800 font-semibold">
                                    Administrator's role can't be changed
                                </div>
                            @else
                                <x-secondary-button wire:click="edit({{$user->id}})">Change role</x-secondary-button>
                            @endif
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @empty
                    {{--Message to be displayed if there are no users--}}
                    <x-table.no-users-found/>
                    {{--End message to be displayed if there are no users--}}
                @endforelse
            </x-slot>
        </x-table.table>
    {{--End users table--}}
    </div>
    <div class="mt-4 ml-2 mr-2">
        {{ $users->links() }}
    </div>
    <div>
    {{--Edit/Create modal--}}
    <x-table.create-edit-modal/>
    {{--End edit/create modal--}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and my component

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Users;

use App\Models\Functionality;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Users extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public User $user;
    public string $search = '';
    public bool $showEditModal = false;

    protected function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            "user.role" => [
                "required",
                "string",
                "in:" .
                collect(Functionality::ROLE)
                    ->keys()
                    ->implode(","),
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function mount(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->showEditModal = true;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $this->user->save();
        $this->showEditModal = false;
        $this->dispatch('notify', $this->user->name.'\'s'.' role changed to '.$this->user->role.'.');
    }




    public function render(): View|Application|Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application
    {
        return view('livewire.users.users', [
            'users' => User::search('name', $this->search)->paginate('5'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Also heres the user model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasTeams;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

/**
 * @method static search(string $string, string $search)
 * @property mixed $name
 * @property mixed $role
 */
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use HasTeams;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'role'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];
}
```

the problem is displayed when page is loaded and when i go to change user's role nothing gets executed. What am i doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

is was expecting for the users role to be changed and a notification to be displayed confirming that the users role is changed

Comment: Check if the `$users` is null: `dd($users)`.

Comment: $user is not null because data is displayed on the page but when i click the button to open the edit modal to edit the users role nothing is displayed on the modal and the save method doesn't execute

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of questions for you, and by addressing them you may resolve the issue.

First, you seem to set a user when mounting. But why? You shouldn't have a user at the start because you first have to select a User to edit right?

So I think what you can do is remove the `mount` function entirely and make the user nullable.

`public User|null $user = null;`

Secondly, is it possible for some user to have no role. Because if they don't have any, that would explain why it's `null`.

You can fix it by using `$user?->role` instead. So for example:

`@if($user?->role == 'admin')`

Also you didn't share the edit model so we can't see that.

*PS. thnx for using `forelse` I didn't know that blade directive very helpfull*

Comment: i removed the mount method and still the same thing. Secondly user does have to have a role because the gates are defined based on the users role and different things get displayed for different user roles. Also i added the user model. Thank you for noticing that